Setting annotation as null for metadata in K8 pod definition
I am using helm template library and somehow I am in a condition where my env.yaml file doe snot have any key for pod annotations and helm is setting annotation : null. Offcourse this is intended behavior.
my questions is will there be unintended behavior or error if I set annotation as null instead of setting as {}.
_deployment.yaml
{{- define "library-chart.deployment" -}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "library-chart.fullname" . }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml .Values.podAnnotations | nindent 4 }}
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    {{- include "library-chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}

Helm diff
 + apiVersion: apps/v1
 + kind: Deployment
 + metadata:
 +   name: xxxx
 +   annotations:
 +     null

...

Even in K8 document there is no mentions of valid/invalid use of null for annotation
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/

You can easily make the entire annotations: block conditional on some value being set.  For example:
metadata:
{{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
  annotations:
{{ . | toYaml | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}

This will capture both the cases of the user-provided annotations being empty ({}) and not present at all (null).
with does two things.  It acts as a conditional like an if statement, so if its expression is "falsey" then the block won't be emitted.  It also rebinds the special variable . to its expression, which then gets used in the toYaml line.
